# How can I obtain the parent folder of another folder?

Tags: python, windows, django, linux, path

In my settings file I have the following lines:

```
import os
import sys

PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(__file__)
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "apps"))
file_path = os.path.join(os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__)),"..",  "webapp.cfg")
```

Under Windows if `os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))` is `D:\Projects\Test\src\test` in `file_path` I will have `D:\Projects\Test\src\webapp.cfg`. This doesn't work under Ubuntu 8.04.

**EDIT1:** I am running Ubuntu 8.04 on a virtual machine. I have Python 2.5.2 version installed on it.

Comment: what does "doesn't work" mean? does your computer explode? do you get "pink unicorn" in `file_path`? It works for me.

Comment: Are the versions of python different?  8.04 is quite an old release of Ubuntu and so the default python installation would be of the same age.

Comment: It says No such file or directory: '/home/Projects/Test/src/test/../webapp.cfg

Comment: @Seitaridis: well, is there such a file?

Comment: You might want to consider adding `file_path = os.path.normpath(file_path)` to eliminate the up-level reference (/../).  I doubt that will fix your problem, though.  Hence the comment instead of answer. :)

Comment: @chaz8705 Please answer the question so I could choose it as my answer. It worked.

Comment: that's not how filepaths look on ubuntu, and not it doesn't have to be normalised.

Comment: That was the Windows path. Under Linux it said No such file or directory: '/home/Projects/Test/src/test/../webapp.cfg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `file_path = os.path.normpath(file_path)` to eliminate the up-level reference (/../).

Answer (score 0):

```
parent = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(directory, ".."))
```